# Showing homeomorphism of unions

Tags: general-topology

Show that $(0, 1) \cup (2, 3)$ is homeomorphic to $(−10, −8) \cup (8, 10).$ I understand why they would be homeomorphic because they have the same topological structure, but I really do not understand how to show that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Find a homeomorphism between them.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: How do I find homeomorphisms? my textbook and my professor only explains what they are conceptually using an example of a circle (0, 2 $\pi$]

Comment: You find homeomorphisms by working out appropriate formulas for them. Do you know how to work out a formula $f(x)$ for a continuous, bijective function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with continuous inverse, and having the property that $f(0)=-10$ and $f(1)=-8$? If so, it will follow that $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $(0,1)$ to $(-10,-8)$, and you're halfway there.

Comment: yes! that is really helpful! thank you! I have 2 functions that are homeomorphisms. Is there a rule that I can use to say the union of the two functions is also homeomorphic or do I need another equation.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Find separate homeomorphisms $(0,1)\to(-10,-8)$ and $(2,3)\to(8,10)$, and take their 'union'.